# How to toggle a Boolean attribute in a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action that simply toggles the `#active` attribute to the opposite boolean state:

- If `@blog.active == true` then `update` it to inactive
- If `@blog.active == false` then `update` it to active

I got the following custom action in a controller to work, but there has to be some Rails way to more elegantly do this:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

  ...    

  def toggle_active
    if @blog.active?
      @blog.update(active: false)
    else
      @blog.update(active: true)
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a Rails way of updating a boolean attribute to the opposite boolean state?

Comment: How about `@blog.update(active: !@blog.active?)`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

ActiveRecord has the `toggle` and `toggle!` methods which do this. Just keep in mind that the `toggle!` method skips validation checks.

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

  ...    

  def toggle_active
    @blog.toggle!(:active)
  end

end
```

If you want to run validations you can do

```
@blog.toggle(:active).save
```

You can read the source code for the methods [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/22d9b3e83e03836c5b5d5b05be87ef9467805107/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L729-L752)

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Using nothing else than Rails already provides.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that toggle accepts 1 value at a time. FWIW

Answer (score 21):

Active Record's [`toggle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle) and [`toggle!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle-21) methods handle toggling a Boolean attribute:

```
def toggle_active
  @blog.toggle(:active).save
end
```

```
def toggle_active
  @blog.toggle!(:active)
end
```

`toggle` changes the attribute, but doesn't save the change to the database (so a separate call to `save` or `save!` is needed).

`toggle!` changes the attribute and saves the record, but bypasses the model's validations.

Comment: Do i get a point for the same exact answer 2 full seconds before yours? It's funny how we came up the almost the same answer at the exact same time :)

Comment: @robertoplancarte upvotes for both of you, thanks for helping me with an simple answer :-)

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that toggle accepts 1 value at a time. FWIW

Answer (score 14):

Rails provides [`toggle`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle) for this, but **it's not atomic**, and you still have to call `save` and consider validations. The bang-method alternative, will handle persistence for you, but validations are skipped.

It's probably better to be explicit about what you're wanting to do here. If this action is the result of a form POST or an XHR request, accept the actual value you want to set (RESTful) instead of expecting the client to be aware of the current state of the database.

So while this works:

```
@blog.toggle(:active)
```

…it's non-deterministic and can result in the opposite of the desired action occurring. I would recommend this instead:

```
class BlogStatusController < ApplicationController 
  # ... boilerplate to load @blog
  def update
    @blog.update(status_params)
  end

protected

  def status_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(status: [:active])
  end
end
```

If you need an atomic toggle, you can easily achieve it with a SQL statement wrapped in a convenient method name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24218418/203130

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that toggle accepts 1 value at a time. FWIW

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
@blog.update(active: !@blog.active?)
```

`!` is your friend:

```
!false # => true
!true # => false
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
@blog.update(active: !@blog.active?)
```

That's pretty compact.